# fill opacity in pic angle acts on the arrow stealth and latex heads

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-angles

I want to add some opacity to draw several angles but the arrowheads (`-latex` and `-stealth`) are modified with `fill opacity` option. At the moment, I'm re-drawing all angles twice, with fill options and without, to keep the arrow heads plain.

First : How can I keep the arrowheads without transparency ?

Second : With `-latex` arrowheads the filled area and the draw lines do not match anymore. There is a small blank between them.

These issues still remain with `arrow` and `arrows.meta` libraries.

Here a MWE :

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes, positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8pt]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{80}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{150}
        
        \draw[-stealth, line width=0.4pt] (-\r-0.6,0) -- (\r+0.65,0) coordinate[label=above left:x] (X) ;
        \draw[-stealth, line width=0.4pt] (0,-\r-0.6) -- (0,\r+0.65) coordinate[label=below right:y] (Y) ;
        \draw (\r,-1.85*\r) -- (\r,1.85*\r);
        \draw (0,0) coordinate (O) circle(\r);
        %% Valeurs d'angles
        \coordinate (A) at (\A:\r);
        \coordinate (B) at (\B:\r);
        
        %% Représentation des angles
        \pic["$\beta$", draw, blue, fill=blue!30,  angle eccentricity=1.7, angle radius=0.4cm, -stealth, pic text options={xshift=-13pt}] {angle=X--O--B};
        \pic["$\alpha$", draw, teal!70!black, fill=black!30, fill opacity=0.6,  angle eccentricity=1.5, angle radius=0.7cm, -latex, pic text options={text opacity=1}] {angle=X--O--A};
        
        \draw (O) -- (A.center);
        \draw (O) -- (B.center);
        
        \draw[-stealth, line width=0.4pt] (0,0) -- (X);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here highlighted problems :
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just loading the `arrows.meta` library won't change any arrow tips (except the special `>`), it provides its own with capitalized words: `Stealth` and `Latex`/`LaTeX` in this case.

Use those, if you want to use the power of `arrows.meta` or define shortcuts

```
\tikzset{
  stealth/.tip = Stealth,
  latex/.tip = LaTeX,
}
```

overwriting the predefined tips.

Your **second problem** is easily solved by loading the [`bending` library](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#pgf.bending) which sets the `flex` arrow key. (The default is `quick` which can be set by doing `\tikzset{arrows={[quick]}}`.)

(Background: The `angle` library separates the filling and drawing in two separate paths (and on two different layers) which desyncs these two actions. The arrow tip offsets the curve by the tip length on a straight line which leads to this malformed curve.)

For your **first problem** I offer a new arrow key: `fill opacity`.
Since opacity and filled arrow tips never place nicely together I set this to `1` in the preamble.

I've also added `text opacity=1` to the preamble for the `angle` pic. Seems to be a good default.

By the way, instead of `"<label>", pic text options={<options>}` you can write `"<label>" {<options>}` where the braces are even optional if they contain no comma.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, angles, bending, quotes, positioning, calc}
\pgfset{arrow keys/fill opacity/.code=
  \pgfarrowsaddtooptions{\pgfsetfillopacity{#1}}}
\tikzset{arrows={[fill opacity=1]}} % seems right to declare this globally
\tikzset{pics/angle/.append style={/tikz/text opacity=1}}% this, too
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8pt]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{80}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{150}

\draw[-Stealth, line width=0.4pt] (-\r-0.6,0) -- (\r+0.65,0)
  coordinate[label=above left:x] (X) ;
\draw[-Stealth, line width=0.4pt] (0,-\r-0.6) -- (0,\r+0.65)
  coordinate[label=below right:y] (Y) ;
\draw (\r,-1.85*\r) -- (\r,1.85*\r);
\draw (0,0) coordinate (O) circle(\r);
%% Valeurs d'angles
\coordinate (A) at (\A:\r);
\coordinate (B) at (\B:\r);

%% Représentation des angles
\pic["$\beta$",  draw, blue, fill=blue!30,
  angle eccentricity=1.7, angle radius=0.4cm, -Stealth,
  pic text options={xshift=-13pt}] {angle=X--O--B};
\pic["$\alpha$", draw, teal!70!black, fill=black!30, fill opacity=0.6,
  angle eccentricity=1.5, angle radius=0.7cm, -Latex] {angle=X--O--A};

\draw (O) -- (A.center);
\draw (O) -- (B.center);

\draw[-Stealth, line width=0.4pt] (0,0) -- (X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Nice. Seems to me that `opacity` and `fill opacity` could/should have been included arrow options.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I thought there was a discussion about opacity and arrow tips around the topic of `transparency group`s but I can't find it. The manual states however that “[i]n general, it is a good idea not to add arrow tips to paths that are filled.” Funnily, enough, the `angle` pic doesn't actually, internally, but by the nature of its definition and how pics work the `fill opacity` still applies to a path that isn't even filled (but a subpath, the arrow tip, is). It's really an annoying issue, especially with different opacities for stroke and fill.

Comment: Complete answer for solutions, explanations and tips. Thanks ! I understand the internal design inducing the behaviour. Do you know if it is planned to be fixed in the future ? It seems a bit odd to me and I'm not sure it is the desired result. But maybe, like dominoes, a small change to fix it could results in bigger issues for such library of pgf. Anyway, accepted !

Comment: @Piroooh The `angle` pic (and its library) was probably the first real pic and was the only that came with PGF/TikZ originally (the newer `folding` library also provides pics). The code has barely changed since 2013. I would construct the pic very differently although the decoupling of fill and draw has some validity if you're using the pic on the same path on which you're drawing the corner. (I have thoughts on this that are too long for a comment.) Even if it were one path, without `bending` the arrow would look bad. The `opacity` thing – see my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

A small, mostly off-topic variation of nice @Qrrbrbirbel answer (+1) which already solve your main problem. In my MWE are changed:

- definitions of arrows
- definition for `pic` style is common
- a wee bit shorter code

All for exercise and joy ...

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                backgrounds, bending,
                quotes}
\pgfset{arrow keys/fill opacity/.code=
    \pgfarrowsaddtooptions{\pgfsetfillopacity{#1}}  % <--- new arrow option!
        }
\tikzset{
          arr/.style = {-{#1[fill opacity=1]}, thin},
        arr/.default = Stealth,
my angle/.style args = {#1/#2/#3/#4}{draw=#1, arr=#2,
                        fill=#1!30, fill opacity=#3,
                        angle radius = #4,
                        angle eccentricity=1.3},
my angle/.default    = {blue/Triangle/1/5mm},
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8pt]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{\r+0.7}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{80}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{150}

% coordonnés
\draw[arr] (-\R,0) -- (\R,0)   coordinate[label=below  left:$x$] (X);
\draw[arr] (0,-\R) -- (0,\R)   coordinate[label=below right:$y$] (Y);
% cercle
\draw (0,0) coordinate (O) circle(\r);
%% Valeurs d'angles
\coordinate (A) at (\A:\r);
\coordinate (B) at (\B:\r);

%% Représentation des angles
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\pic[my angle,  "$\beta$",
     pic text options={xshift=-11pt}]   {angle=X--O--B};
\pic[my angle=red/Stealth/0.6/7mm,
                "$\alpha$"]             {angle=X--O--A};
}
\draw[line join=bevel] (A) -- (O) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]